# Homomorphic encryption poll for multiple people

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I understand for homomorphic encryption, you can perform operations on the ciphertext such that:
$E(x_1)+E(x_2)=E(x_1+x_2)$ which can allow you to work out the sum of the <s>plaintext</s>  encryption

I have two questions:

1. How does homomorphic encryption work for choosing A, B and C. I know to vote for A or B, you can use 1s or 0s then sum up the ciphertext to see how many voted for A. Does homomorphic encryption not work here. If so, what other method could you use then?
2. What stops someone from submitting a vote of 50 e.g. E(50). As the votes are encrypted, is there a way to check the computation was indeed correct?

Comment: You cannot "work out the sum of the plaintext"; you can only obtain an encryption of the sum. Also, homomorphic encryption is not a voting scheme, it just allows you to encrypt. Hence, it does not (want to) prevent you from encrypting 50.

Comment: Evoting is *much* more complicated than 'lets apply a simple homomorphic encryption'; some of the issues you mentioned (such as 'how do we prevent someone from submitting a vote of 50'), others you didn't (such as 'how do we prove to someone that we included their vote, and in a way that they cannot prove that to a third party', the latter being in there to frustrate vote buying...)